# How to remove duplicate lines while keeping the order AND ignoring case?

Tags: awk

```
[user@notebook ~]$ printf '1\n5\n3\n3\n4\n2\nA\nB\na\n'
1
5
3
3
4
2
A
B
a
[user@notebook ~]$ 
[user@notebook ~]$ printf '1\n5\n3\n3\n4\n2\nA\nB\na\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
1
5
3
4
2
A
B
a
[user@notebook ~]$ 
[user@notebook ~]$ printf '1\n5\n3\n3\n4\n2\nA\nB\na\n' | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} !seen[$0]++'
1
5
3
4
2
A
B
a
[user@notebook ~]$
```

**Q:** how can I ignore the case? So there should be only "A" or "a" left..

Comment: Easier: `printf "%s\n" 1 5 3 3 4 2 A B a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf '1\n5\n3\n3\n4\n2\nA\nB\na\n' | awk '!seen[tolower($0)]++'
```

produces the output you're looking for.

From the `awk` manual page:

> IGNORECASE Controls the case-sensitivity of all regular expression and string operations. [...] **NOTE: Array subscripting is not affected.**

That's why using `IGNORECASE` has no effect.